# Can't use keyboard of "enter" to input value on cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm a Python beginner.I've been referring to some online resources and attempting to create an application with editable cells using WxPython. The program runs smoothly when I use older versions of WxPython (WxPython 2.8) and Python (Python 2.6). However, when I tried upgrading to WxPython 4.0.4 and Python 3.8, the program no longer executes.

Here is my code, and I had changed old command in my code.

I would appreciate any advice or assistance you can provide:

```
import wx
import wx.grid
import string

class UpCaseCellEditor(wx.grid.GridCellEditor):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.grid.GridCellEditor.__init__(self)

    def Create(self, parent, id, evtHandler):
        """
 Called to create the control, which must derive from wx.Control.
 *Must Override*
 """
        self._tc = wx.TextCtrl(parent, id, "")
        self._tc.SetInsertionPoint(0)
        self.SetControl(self._tc)

        if evtHandler:
            self._tc.PushEventHandler(evtHandler)

        self._tc.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)

    def SetSize(self, rect):
        """
 Called to position/size the edit control within the cell rectangle.
 If you don't fill the cell (the rect) then be sure to override
 PaintBackground and do something meaningful there.
 """
        self._tc.SetDimensions(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width+2, rect.height+2,
                               wx.SIZE_ALLOW_MINUS_ONE)

    def BeginEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        """
 Fetch the value from the table and prepare the edit control
 to begin editing.  Set the focus to the edit control.
 *Must Override*
 """
        self.startValue = grid.GetTable().GetValue(row, col)
        self._tc.SetValue(self.startValue)
        self._tc.SetInsertionPointEnd()
        self._tc.SetFocus()
        self._tc.SetSelection(0, self._tc.GetLastPosition())

    def EndEdit(self, row, col, grid):
        """
 Complete the editing of the current cell. Returns True if the value
 has changed.  If necessary, the control may be destroyed.
 *Must Override*
 """
        changed = False

        val = self._tc.GetValue()

        if val != self.startValue:
            changed = True
            grid.GetTable().SetValue(row, col, val) # update the table

        self.startValue = ''
        self._tc.SetValue('')
        return changed

    def Reset(self):
        """
 Reset the value in the control back to its starting value.
 *Must Override*
 """
        self._tc.SetValue(self.startValue)
        self._tc.SetInsertionPointEnd()

    def Clone(self):
        """
 Create a new object which is the copy of this one
 *Must Override*
 """
        return UpCaseCellEditor()

    def StartingKey(self, evt):
        """
 If the editor is enabled by pressing keys on the grid, this will be
 called to let the editor do something about that first key if desired.
 """
        self.OnChar(evt)
        if evt.GetSkipped():
            self._tc.EmulateKeyPress(evt)

    def OnChar(self, evt):
        key = evt.GetUnicodeKey()
        if key > 255:
            evt.Skip()
            return 
        char = chr(key)
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            char = char.upper()
            self._tc.WriteText(char)
        else:
            evt.Skip()

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Grid Editor",
                          size=(640,480))

        grid = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        grid.CreateGrid(50,50)
        grid.SetDefaultEditor(UpCaseCellEditor())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello everyone,

I'd like to keep a record of my learning journey. I've found that upgrading the version can easily solve the problem.